# Is there a way to get a service in Android synchronously?

Tags: android, android-service

I need to grab a service synchronously in Android. I'm sure it's already running, I just need to access it in my adapter. Should I just pass a reference once the service becomes available, or can I use something to the effect of `context.getService(...)` to get it? What is the recommended solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have an activity where the adapter is created and destroyed. Therefore the adapter's lifecycle should match the lifecycle of your activity. The conclusion would be to pass a reference of the service to the adapter on its creation, as it is the activity that binds and unbinds the service. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you are interested in is the concept of making a bound service.  Take a look at the Local Service Sample example on the `Service` SDK page:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

This example shows how to bind to a service you create so you can get a standing reference to it and make direct calls to it while you are bound.  When you bind/unbind to a service in this fashion, you also do not have to worry about calling start and stop explicitly.  The service is only running as long as there is at least one component bound to it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: But binding to the service is asynchronous, so this isn't a synchronous solution at all.

Comment: True, but the Binder interface is the only way to gain direct access to a Service object in the requested fashion. One would not do the bind operation at the moment the service is needed, but rather do it in such a way as to follow the lifecycle of an Activity or other system component.  Might need more info about the problem to propose a better solution.

Comment: @Devunwired Depending on when/where you need access to the service, this might just be a design shortcoming. I would really like to have access to a service in Activity.onResume(). However, I've tried calling bindService() in both Application.onCreate() and Activity.onCreate() but ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected() doesn't get called by the time Activity.onResume() runs.  It appears that the lifecycle events get queued up back-to-back in a way that ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected() won't run until after an Activity is already running.  If you have any ideas, I would like to hear them.